# Debug on IIS instead of WebDev server

Tags: asp.net, .net, debugging, iis

I am developing a web application. My code worked fine on the WebDev server in VS2010. Then, I hosted it on remote IIS, because my windows 7 home basic doesn't have IIS, and almost all code fails. So I had to rewrite it using helpers for links, ResolveUrl and many other functions.

How can I host an application while debugging on remote IIS (not on WebDev or local IIS) automatically?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of code/html that caused you problems?

Comment: Were you deploying into the root of a site or an application folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install IIS Express. IIS express is more mature in terms of emulating real IIS 7. For more information on IIS express refer [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx). HTH

Comment: I have not yet worked with IIS express but according to MS guidance WebDev will soon be replaced by IIS express. You can try using it.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider developing you application using [MebMatrix](http://www.asp.net/web-pages-old/overview/exploring-webmatrix), which is a free development environment that includes IIS Express. It's easy to learn and doesn't require Visual Studio.